# Different addresses from same mnemonic?

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib, cardano-address

I want to generate an old Byron address.  However, depending on which software I use (`cardano-address` or `cardano-serialization-lib`), I get a different result for the same mnemonic phrase.  Here is my code for `cardano-serialization-lib`, run online with https://npm.runkit.com/:

```
var bip39 = require('bip39');
var CardanoWasm = require('@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-nodejs');
var b58 = require('base58-js');

var digits = '0123456789abcdef'.split('')
var encodeLookup = []
var decodeLookup = {}

for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
  var ones = i & 0xf
  var sixteens = i >> 4 & 0xf
  var string = digits[sixteens] + digits[ones]
  encodeLookup[i] = string
  decodeLookup[string] = i
  //console.log(decodeLookup)
}

encode = function (array) {
  var length = array.length
  var string = ''
  var i = 0
  while (i < length) {
    string += encodeLookup[array[i++]]
  }
  return string
}

function harden(num){
  return 0x80000000 + num;
}

const entropy = bip39.mnemonicToEntropy(
  [ "test", "walk", "nut", "penalty", "hip", "pave", "soap", "entry", "language", "right", "filter", "choice" ].join(' ')
);

const rootKey = CardanoWasm.Bip32PrivateKey.from_bip39_entropy(
  Buffer.from(entropy, 'hex'),
  Buffer.from(''),
);

const accountKey = rootKey
  .derive(harden(44)) // purpose
  .derive(harden(1815)) // coin type
  .derive(harden(0)); // account #0

const utxoPubKey = accountKey
  .derive(0) // external
  .derive(0)
  .to_public();

const byronAddr = CardanoWasm.ByronAddress.icarus_from_key(
  utxoPubKey, // Ae2* style icarus address
  CardanoWasm.NetworkInfo.mainnet().protocol_magic()
);

const address = byronAddr.to_address();

console.log(b58.binary_to_base58(address.to_bytes()));
```

I get **Ae2tdPwUPEZ7sZ29n6td4jkbnK31Q2BdQQ2rrMGYAXeEjVznrixjc5PZ2rj** as the address.

Here is my command-line for `cardano-address` (yes, I'm on Windows):

```
ECHO test walk nut penalty hip pave soap entry language right filter choice | "%CD%\cardano-address.exe" key from-recovery-phrase Byron | "%CD%\cardano-address.exe" key child 44H/1815H/0H/0/0 | "%CD%\cardano-address.exe" key public --with-chain-code | "%CD%\cardano-address.exe" address bootstrap --network-tag mainnet & ECHO.
```

Here I get **Ae2tdPwUPEZ9xFkLoCFGvtgrHc5K5jr3n1wMuVLRXSZZ32iGGyfQpZQcK6f**.

Which one is correct?

Comment: `cardano-addresses` is official IOHK software, but the `cardano-serialization-lib` is listed on cardano.org's developers site, so it must be approved somehow, yet they don't agree on address generation.  This seems like a huge problem.  If I can't get an answer here, does anyone know a better place to raise this issue?

Comment: you can try to ask on https://forum.cardano.org

Comment: You should get an answer in here as the majority of the Cardano devs and main contributors are part of this community. If you don't get an answer here, then I guess we have a problem...